# How to properly link and include libraries?

Tags: c++, linker, glew, freeglut, physx

It's the first time I prepare a pretty complex application in C++ (Visual Studio 2010) and I have serious linking problems which gave me a solid headache (maybe cause I've never got what it's all about).

I'm implementing fluid flow simulator using:
- NVidia PhysX (SDK 3.2.3)
- glew (1.9)
- freeglut (2.8.1)
- gltools library (addon to OpenGL Superbible 5th)

I have no idea how to properly set Release/Debug and MD/MDd/MT/MTd options to get everything working.

- I can compile freeglut with MD/MDd/MT/MTd and also with Relese/Release-Static/Debug/Debug-Static solution configurations
- I can compile gltools with MD/MDd/MT/MTd and also with Relese/Debug
- PhysX is precompiled lib and dll files (I have no idea what options were used in compiling process)
- Same is about glew

I tried a lot of configurations but all the time i get compilation errors like

```
defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs;
```

or

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  Exactly one of NDEBUG and _DEBUG needs to be defined by preprocessor
```

I read that It's all about setting mentioned configuration in a right way, but I actually can't do it.

What should be right configuration (and why?) and which libraries should I link with lib files and which with dll? Im kind of newbie with C++ so please try to explain it clearly.

That's 'include part' of my application (It was pretty similar and it worked before i accidentally broke it):

```
//#define WIN32
#include <windows.h>        // Must have for Windows platform builds

#include <GLTools.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLBatch.h>
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLShaderManager.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>
#include <StopWatch.h>

//#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL\glew.h>            // OpenGL Extension "autoloader"
//#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
//#include <GL\gl.h>            // Microsoft OpenGL headers (version 1.1 by themselves)

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <PxPhysicsAPI.h> 
#include <extensions/PxExtensionsAPI.h> 
#include <extensions/PxDefaultErrorCallback.h>
#include <extensions/PxDefaultAllocator.h> 
#include <extensions/PxDefaultSimulationFilterShader.h>
#include <extensions/PxDefaultCpuDispatcher.h>
#include <extensions/PxShapeExt.h>
#include <foundation/PxMat33.h> 

#include <pxtask/PxCudaContextManager.h>
#include <physxprofilesdk\PxProfileZoneManager.h>

#include <extensions/PxSimpleFactory.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "PhysX3_x86.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "PhysX3Common_x86.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "PxTask.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "PhysX3Extensions.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "PhysXProfileSDK")
```

I'm not sure if last lanes are necessary if everything is set well (found it somewhere in google and it worked).

If you need more information or more detailed error log with some configuration, just tell me and I'll provide it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Debug /MDd

```
PxTask.lib(CudaWrapper.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultSimulationFilterShader.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtSimpleFactory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultCpuDispatcher.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultErrorCallback.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtRigidBodyExt.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtCpuWorkerThread.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysXProfileSDK.lib(PxProfileEventImpl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\dev\SPHFluids\SPHFluids\Debug\SPHFluids.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Release /MDd

```
PxTask.lib(CudaWrapper.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultSimulationFilterShader.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultErrorCallback.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultCpuDispatcher.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtSimpleFactory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtCpuWorkerThread.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtRigidBodyExt.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysXProfileSDK.lib(PxProfileEventImpl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0
1>C:\dev\SPHFluids\SPHFluids\Release\SPHFluids.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Release /MTd

```
PxTask.lib(CudaWrapper.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultSimulationFilterShader.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultErrorCallback.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtDefaultCpuDispatcher.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtSimpleFactory.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtCpuWorkerThread.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysX3Extensions.lib(ExtRigidBodyExt.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>PhysXProfileSDK.lib(PxProfileEventImpl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fclose.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fwrite already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fwrite.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fgetc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fgetc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fprintf.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0
1>C:\dev\SPHFluids\SPHFluids\Release\SPHFluids.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Everything without d (/MD /MT):

```
c:\dev\soft\physx-3.2.3_pc_sdk_core\include\foundation\pxpreprocessor.h(318): fatal error C1189: #error :  Exactly one of NDEBUG and _DEBUG needs to be defined by preprocessor
```

and it's only one configuration of lib files. I can compile gltools and freeglut other way or set #define GLEW_STATIC or #define FREEGLUT_STATIC other way... It's just too many options for a newbie. :)

One more:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class physx::PxFlags<enum physx::PxFilterFlag::Enum,unsigned short> __cdecl physx::PxDefaultSimulationFilterShader(unsigned int,struct physx::PxFilterData,unsigned int,struct physx::PxFilterData,class physx::PxFlags<enum physx::PxPairFlag::Enum,unsigned short> &,void const *,unsigned int)" (?PxDefaultSimulationFilterShader@physx@@YA?AV?$PxFlags@W4Enum@PxFilterFlag@physx@@G@1@IUPxFilterData@1@I0AAV?$PxFlags@W4Enum@PxPairFlag@physx@@G@1@PBXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall physx::PxDefaultErrorCallback::~PxDefaultErrorCallback(void)" (??1PxDefaultErrorCallback@physx@@UAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall physx::PxDefaultErrorCallback::PxDefaultErrorCallback(void)" (??0PxDefaultErrorCallback@physx@@QAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class physx::PxProfileZoneManager & __cdecl physx::PxProfileZoneManager::createProfileZoneManager(class physx::PxFoundation *)" (?createProfileZoneManager@PxProfileZoneManager@physx@@SAAAV12@PAVPxFoundation@2@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class physx::pxtask::CudaContextManager * __cdecl physx::pxtask::createCudaContextManager(class physx::PxFoundation &,class physx::pxtask::CudaContextManagerDesc const &,class physx::PxProfileZoneManager *)" (?createCudaContextManager@pxtask@physx@@YAPAVCudaContextManager@12@AAVPxFoundation@2@ABVCudaContextManagerDesc@12@PAVPxProfileZoneManager@2@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class physx::PxDefaultCpuDispatcher * __cdecl physx::PxDefaultCpuDispatcherCreate(unsigned int,unsigned int *)" (?PxDefaultCpuDispatcherCreate@physx@@YAPAVPxDefaultCpuDispatcher@1@IPAI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PxCreateFoundation
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PxCreatePlane
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PxRegisterArticulations
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PxRegisterHeightFields
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PxCreateBasePhysics
1>C:\dev\SPHFluids\SPHFluids\Release\SPHFluids.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

It's with all these PhysX pragmas commented.

Comment: "defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs;" this could be that the other libs you are linking with are the wrong configuration (linking a Release lib to a Debug application) or from the wrong compiler (linking a VS2008 lib with visual studio 2010) or that you selected the wrong link setting for your runtime.

Comment: Please post the exact full error message.

Comment: In the applications project settings there is a linker option in "Linker->General" called "Link Library Dependencies". Changing this setting to "no" _may_ help if all of libraries are DLL's.

Comment: I added logs.
@Captain Obvlious I have a lot of dll files in Release and Debug directories (where .exe should be created). I have also a lot of .lib files in lib directory of my project.

Comment: I don't have a proper answer for you but the problem is the library was compiled with a different version of VC. You didn't say which version of the SDK you are using so it's hard to say anything more than that.

Comment: You mean PhysX SDK version? I wrote it. It's 3.2.3

Comment: I can't confirm it myself but that's likely your problem. Go back to 3.2.1 or 3.2.0. Those versions have almost the same problem but in reverse - You get the errors on VS2012 but AFAIK not 2010

Answer (score 0):

one thing that may point you towards the solution is that physx 3.2.3 lib files are built with /MT option as indicated in their documentation (this is a part of the physx zip in the documentation folder) :

"Note
The static libraries we provide with the Windows binary distribution are linked against the Multi-Threaded static C Run-Time (CRT) libraries. This means that your application must also use the same CRT flavor. If you need to use a different CRT version, you must upgrade to our source license. The source distribution can simply be recompiled using different CRT settings.
"
So if you are planning to link against these, you must use the /MT flag for all your other libraries as well.

Comment: This is what I hate about using PhysX lib in a large project. It forces you to recompile every single library with static runtime library flag. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Add a `#define NDEBUG` in the file where you include physics headers. This will remove your NDEBUG issue.